# dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN2cv6imreadERKNSt3 when run a simple code on MAC OS 10.10

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, shared-libraries, dyld

I'm trying to run the following code on MAC OS 10.10:

```
#include <cv.h>    
#include <highgui.h>    

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() 
{
    Mat img = imread("xxx.jpg");
    imshow("image", img);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

This code can be built successfully. But, when I run it, I always get the error message:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: 
__ZN2cv6imreadERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEEi
Referenced from:    
/Users/Coldmoon/ComputerVisionApps/opencvTest/Build/Products/Debug/opencvTest
Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
```

I have two different versions of opencv. One is built with `libstdc++`, the other is built with `libc++`. Both are opencv 2.4.9. I want to build the above code using `libc++` opencv.

So, in the Xcode 6.1, I set `Header Search Path` and `Library Search Path` to point to `libc++` opencv which is in  `/Users/Coldmoon/MyLibraries/opencv-2.4.9` and set `C++ Standard Library` to `libc++`.

My question: It seems that compiler does not link the `libc++` opencv but `libstdc++` opencv instead which is in `/usr/local/lib`.

I'm totally confused. Is there anything I miss?

Comment: How do you tell linker which version of opencv to use? I mean, do you have both libraries in `/Users/Coldmoon/MyLibraries/opencv-2.4.9` or only `libc++` one? Also, `libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib` may have install path equal to `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib`, so after you link to the library in your home, linked application will look for the library in the different folder. As a first step try to run your app with `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Coldmoon/MyLibraries/opencv-2.4.9`.

Comment: Thank you very much!It worked! I just set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` value in Xcode's Environment Variables. Let `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Coldmoon/MyLibraries/opencv-2.4.9/release/installed/lib`. But, I still don't understand the reason. In my opinion, when I tell Xcode the positions of `Header Search Path` and `Library Search Path`(point to libc++ opencv which is in `/Users/Coldmoon/MyLibraries/opencv-2.4.9/release/installed`), the information is clear enough! Xcode should know which library to link. Why do I need to tell Xcode the value of `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: By the way, the `libstdc++ opencv` is in `/usr/local/lib` which Xcode tends to link originally.

Comment: `Library Search Path` only tells linker where to get library to link executable to. But it doesn't tell dynamic loader where to search for the library when the executable is started. You can run `otool -L your_executable` to find out where dynamic loader will look for `libopencv`. Then run `otool -L <path_to_libopencv_from_previous_otool_run>` to find which standard library `libstdc++` or `libc++` is used by referenced `libopencv`.

Comment: For the first step, I've run `tool -L my_executable`. It gave me `lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.9)` and so on. However, it is a relative path, not a absolute path. So I couldn't do the second step. Is there any way in which I can get the absolute path?

Comment: If it's relative path, dynamic linker will use standard library search paths to look for the library. This is where `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` comes into play - it overrides the look up order. Read `man dyld` for more info about this.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply to me. I really appreciate it. Could you write the answer in the below so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Library Search Paths` tells linker where to search for the library to link to. But when the executable is run, the library may be searched by dynamic loader (`dyld`) in different places. This is controlled by 'Install Name' of the library that may be queried by `otool -D libFoo.dylib`.

So, for example, if the library you are linking to is in `/bar/libFoo.dylib`, but its install name is `/baz/libFoo.dylib`, you need to put `/bar` in `Library Search Paths`, but when you run the binary it'll be searched in `/baz`.

You can also find out where the libraries are seachred when the executable is run by `otool -L <executable>`.

If the path to shared library is not absolute, dynamic loader tries to load it from some standard paths. If you set `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` environment variable, `dyld` will log the filenames of the libraries it tries to load to `stderr`. You can override the paths where `dyld` searches for libraries by setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable (`:`-separated list of paths).

More info about `dyld` environment variables can be found in `man dyld`.